# How can I use Telerik RadGrid's filter expression to filter a custom List<Document> data object?

Tags: asp.net, linq, telerik-grid

I am using Telerik RadGrid with LINQExpressions enabled.

I am binding this grid to data that I retrieve from Cache in NeedDataSource event as in code below.

The problem is, when I step through my code after inputting a filter, then I get this as filter expression - **"(iif(MemberName == null, \"\", MemberName).ToString().StartsWith(\"T\"))"**. How would I use this with my listFromCache object? Perhaps, some LINQ trick? MemberName is a property of Document object. It seems its impossible to use the FilterExpression that I get in code-behind from RadGrid's object model.

I am using C#.

```
 List<Document> listFromCache = Cache[dataCacheName] as List<Document>;

 if (listFromCache != null)
 {

   //FILTER listFromCache here

 }
```

Comment: not sure I understand... are you looking for something like this?  var listFromCache = (Cache[dataCacheName] as List<Document>).Where(doc => doc.MemberName != null && doc.MemberName.ToString().StartsWith("T"));

Comment: @StephenOberauer, Yes, except that, I would like to directly use Telerik's provided FilterExpression that I get in code-behind? Not sure if that is even possible.